# Prevent input dissapears when navigating

Tags: html

In page 1 I have option to navigate to page 2 like: `<a href="Options.html">Page 2</a>`. inside page 2 I have some input from user.

I have the following secnario:

1. User fill some input in page 2.
2. User navigates to page 1
3. User navigate back to page 2.

with this secnario all user input that was at page 2 dissapears now and needed to type all again. bacause it creates a new page 2 every time when navigating to that page.

my question is how to avoid thi, I mean I want that if user typed already some stuff at page 2 I want that it will "remember" that input or to navigate to same old page without creating a new one every time.

Comment: Use Cookie or localstorage for this

Comment: @porky which client  side coding language you are using.

Comment: @PranavMS JavaScript...